# NumberFormatException in TestNG dataprovider

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I have used the below method to enter credentials in an application.

```
public LoginPage enterCredentials(String userName, String password){
        actions.EnterText(userId, userName)
               .EnterText(userPassword, password);
        return this;
```

in which EnterText is defined as below:

```
 public Actions EnterText(ObjectLocator locator, String text){
            driverWait(Integer.parseInt(getProperties("Control_Wait")));
            FindElement(locator).clear();
            FindElement(locator).sendKeys(text);
            return this;
        }
```

And in Test class i have written the below code

```
    public class LoginTests extends TestSetup{
    @Test(dataProvider="Credentials")
    public void loginProxy(String usrName, String usrPassword){
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
        login.navigateUrl()
             .enterCredentials(usrName, usrPassword)
             .clickLogin();
    }
    @DataProvider(name ="Credentials")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];
        data[0][0] = "11";
        data[0][1] = "Priya";
        data[1][0] = "108";
        data[1][1] = "Logan";
        data[2][0] = "36";
        data[2][1] = "Geller";
        return data;
    }
```

Am getting the below error:

> FAILED: loginProxy("11", "Priya") java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   null  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Please help in resolving the same. As per my knowledge this error is caused due to the conversion of integer to string. But am not able to resolve the same.

Comment: `null` can not be parsed as a number. Add the complete stactrace for more help

Comment: But i have passed number and string in the data provider? how is it getting null?

Comment: I guess `getProperties("Control_Wait")` return `null`

Comment: BTW. Take care about Java naming conventions. Method names should start with lower case character `Actions EnterText` should be `Actions enterText`

Comment: @jens sure will take care of Java naming conventions. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Number format exception** is thrown by **parseInt** method of **Integer** class. This definitely shows that method getProperties which is returning 'String' value for key "Control_Wait" is returning null and there may be 'n' number of reasons for that.

Key is not present in properties file.

Value of key is not present in properties file.

Logic of getProperties() to get key value is wrong.

Property file is not initialized or loaded correctly

```
public class PropertyTest {

public static Properties properties = new Properties();

private static void loadProperties() {
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("src/test/resources/property/android.properties");
        properties.load(fis);
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
} 
public static String getProperty(String key) {
    String value = "";
    if (key != "") {
        loadProperties();
        try {
            if (!properties.getProperty(key).trim().isEmpty())
                value = properties.getProperty(key).trim();
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
    }

    return value;
}       

}
```

> > Usage

```
driverWait(Integer.parseInt(getProperty("Control_Wait")));
```

Comment: Never catch NPE. Check if a value is null instead. Also never catch exceptions without handle it